# Missing values in the HttpContext Session when accessed in the WebApi 2.0 custom Authentication Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my web services (WebApi 2.0), I have implemented `IAuthenticationFilter` which checks some values in the `HttpContext.Current.Session` (E.g. HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenId"]) and decides whether user is authorized to proceed or not. I have registered this filter in the `FilterConfig` class like following so that this filter is executed everytime anybody is calling Web Api.

```
config.Filters.Add(new WebApiAuthenticationFilter());
```

My MVC 4 application has a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. This attribute is executed for every controller action. This attribute internally calls my Web Api. When Web Api is called, the authentication filter automatically gets executed which tells user is authorized or not. This is how I come to know about user's authorization status in my MVC application.

I observed that `HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenId"]` returns `null` only for the first Web Api call. Then onwards, I get correct value in the `HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenId"]`.

Questions:

1. Why values in the `Session` are not available in the **`AuthenticationFilter`** during **first Web Api call only**?

Note:

- My Web Api and MVC code runs in the same web application.
- `HttpContext.Current.Session` is NOT null. Only data (like TokenId) stored in Session  is not available.
- **Same TokenId is available if I access `Session` from my MVC custom authorization attribute or inside actual Web Api controller if I let the call proceed upto Web Api controller. The value is missing from `Session` in the `AuthenticationFilter` only.** !
- I know that using Session is not recommended but at present I have to live with it.
- `SessionStateBehavior` is set already to `Required` for the Web Api using following event in the `Global.asax` file.

  protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
  {
          if (IsWebApiRequest())
          {                              HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
          }
  }

Comment: Have you tried accessing the HttpContext.Session on the AuthenticationContext in your IAuthenticationFilter?

Comment: @JonSusiak : Yes. That too does not work. I don't understand why Session values are unavailable in the filter which comes early in the Web Api pipeline. If I let the call reach to Web Api controller, values are available there ! So it seems WebApi infrastructure has something which prevents Session values to be available in the authentication filer for the FIRST time.